# Riemann–von Mangoldt formula: Is $\ln(T/2\pi!)$ the number of non-trivial zeroes along the critical line of the zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta

From the [Riemann–von Mangoldt formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93von_Mangoldt_formula) article in Wikipedia:

> The formula states that the number N(T) of zeros of the zeta function
> with imaginary part greater than 0 and less than or equal to T
> satisfies

$$
N(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{T}{2\pi}}-\frac{T}{2\pi }+O(\ln{T}).
$$

But this just looks like an example of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), so is a better expression simply

$$
N(T)\sim\ln\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}!\right)=\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}+1\right)
$$
or do the higher-order terms differ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here - Stirling (and $\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}+1\right)$) is very precise up to various orders (in other words we know the $\log n$ term, the constant and then one can continue with powers of $1/n$ as long as we wish); for von Mangoldt we just know $\frac{T}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{T}{2\pi}}-\frac{T}{2\pi }$ but $S(T)$ as the reminder is usually denoted and which is more or less the argument of RZ on the critical line is quite mysterious and for example on RH it is actually $o(\log T)$ etc; so beyond the first two terms the analogy breaks down

Comment: Hmm. So I conjecture that $N(T)\sim\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}+1\right)$.

Comment: You are taking it the wrong way: $\frac{T}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{T}{2\pi}}-\frac{T}{2\pi }$ comes from $\text{arg}(\Gamma((1/2+iT)/2))$ ie. from Stirling.